# When using UAA how do you setup a foreign relationship to the user entity?

Tags: jhipster

Other stackoverflow answers and bug reports have discussed setting a one direction relationship with the "user" entity but this won't work in a microservice using UAA authentication because there is no JHI_USER table in the schema.

Answer (score 1):

You just can't because you're crossing service/system boundaries. Imagine you used LDAP or Active Directory to authenticate your users, the only thing you could do is to refer to a user by its login name which is basically an external ID. This is the same with UAA or between 2 microservices.